# Discord Bot can only see itself and no other users in guild

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, discord, discord.py

I have recently been following [this tutorial](https://realpython.com/how-to-make-a-discord-bot-python/) to get myself started with Discord's API. Unfortunately, when I got the part about printing all the users in the guild I hit a wall.

When I try to print all users' names **it only prints the name of the bot and nothing else**. For reference, there are six total users in the guild. The bot has **Administrator privileges**.

```py
import os
import discord

TOKEN = os.environ.get('TOKEN')
client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    for guild in client.guilds:
        print(guild, [member.name for member in guild.members])

client.run(TOKEN)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As of discord.py v1.5.0, you are required to use `Intents` for your bot, you can read more about them by [clicking here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Intents)
In other words, you need to do the following changes in your code -

```
import discord
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')
GUILD = os.getenv('DISCORD_GUILD')

intents = discord.Intents.all()
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    for guild in client.guilds:
        if guild.name == GUILD:
            break

    print(
        f'{client.user} is connected to the following guild: \n' 
        f'{guild.name} (id: {guild.id})'
    )

    # just trying to debug here
    for guild in client.guilds:
        for member in guild.members:
            print(member.name, ' ')

    members = '\n - '.join([member.name for member in guild.members])
    print(f'Guild Members:\n - {members}')
    
client.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: Thank you! Most other answers didn't mention that you had to do `client = discord.Client(intents=intents)` Thanks!

Comment: I am facing same issue in nodejs. Can you please give solution in nodejs too.

Answer (score 17):

1. Enable the **server members intent** near the bottom of the **Bot** tab of your [**Discord Developer Portal**](https://discord.com/developers/applications):

   [image]
2. Change the line `client = discord.Client()` to this:

   ```py
   intents = discord.Intents.default()
   intents.members = True
   client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
   ```

   This makes your bot request the "members" gateway intent.

---

**What are gateway intents?** Intents allow you to subscribe to certain events. For example, if you set `intents.typing = False` your bot won't be sent typing events which can save resources.

**What are privileged intents?** *Privileged* intents (like members and presences) are considered sensitive and require verification by Discord for bots in over 100 servers. For bots that are in less than 100 servers you just need to opt-in at the page shown above.

[A Primer to Gateway Intents](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html)

[Intents API Reference](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Intents)