# discord.py: guild.members returns only bot but no members

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make a Discord bot with Python.

In the Discord Developers interface, on my bot panel, "Privileged Gateway Intents" (SERVER MEMBERS INTENT) is checked.

The bot is on a server (guild) with admin authorizations.
I don't understand why the bot returns only itself, but not me or my friend.

```py
for guild in self.discord_client.guilds:
            print(f"guild found : {guild}")
            print(guild.members)
        for member in guild.members:
            print(member)
```

The code above returns this:

```py
guild found : Testdev   
[<Member id=76277237853886878X name='Dev_Bot' discriminator='6271' bot=True nick=None guild=<Guild id=76114559936167936X name='Testdev' shard_id=None chunked=False member_count=3>>]
```

member count=3, but after this:

```py
for member in list(guild.members):
    print(member)
```

it returns only the bot's ID:

```
Dev_Bot#6271
```

Answer (score 6):

The only useful answer I have found is here:

[Discord Bot can only see itself and no other users in guild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64148371/discord-bot-can-only-see-itself-and-no-other-users-in-guild)

Basically, it says that you have to set the `intents` to be able to see the guild's members.

So, instead of just `client = discord.Client()`, you'll have to do:

```py
...

intents = discord.Intents.all()
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

...
```

or

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
```

if you want to *just* have that intent

Answer (score 3):

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html

Or simply, install version 1.4.2 of the library: `pip install -U discord.py==1.4.2`

Comment: That install is a **downgrade** and it'll only work temporarily. You'll have to switch over to intents _eventually_.