# Python discord.py guild memberlist not work

Tags: python, discord.py

I try

```
 guild = client.get_guild()#input guild-id
    async for member in client.fetch_members(limit=150):
       print(member.name)
```

error code:

> Ignoring exception in on_ready Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "D:\studio\share\crawling\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py",
> line 343, in _run_event
> await coro(*args, **kwargs)   File "D:\studio\onga\main.py", line 20, in on_ready
> async for member in client.fetch_members(limit=150): AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'fetch_members'

[image: sample image]

Comment: Which documentation says that `Client.fetch_members` exists?

Comment: i'm sorry I solved it by referring below

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64215965/discord-python-guild-members-return-only-bot-but-no-members

Comment: I'll try to improve my search skills a bit so that I can solve it myself.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

There is already a simple way to get the member count the `guild.member_count`

````
@bot.command(aliases=["mc"])
async def membercount(ctx):
  guild = ctx.guild
  await ctx.reply(f"There is {guild.member_count} Members In The {guild.name}")```
````