# Count all members with a specific role with Discord Py

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm almost new to programming. I wanted to add a function to my bot to count the amount of members with x role, it'll always be the same role. I've been trying to use `role.members`, but I get the error

> NameError: name 'role' is not defined

Thank you!

Comment: That just means "role" doesn't exist, so you have to define a variable with that name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `len` on `Role.members` but to get a role you do `Guild.get_role(role_id)`

Below is the code:

```py
@bot.command()
async def rolemembers(ctx):
    role = ctx.guild.get_role(ROLE_ID)
    await ctx.send(len(role.members))
```

Comment: Hello and thanks for the help, when I run the command I get 0, I tried printing just the list but it's empty.

Answer (score 1):

probably a bit late but you might want to check using intents in order to use the solution.

Ref: [Discord Bot can only see itself and no other users in guild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64148371/discord-bot-can-only-see-itself-and-no-other-users-in-guild)

Answer (score -1):

Copy me This is the simplest way ever

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands,tasks
intents = discord.Intents.default()  
intents.members = True

#If without intents It will return 0 so it should be like this



bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='?',intents=intents)

@bot.command()
#You can create any name 
async def users_in_role(ctx,role: discord.Role):  
  
  #this will give the length of the users in role in an embed
  embed = discord.Embed(description = 
  f"**Users in role:**\n{len(role.members)}")
  await ctx.send(embed=embed)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
  print('bot online')

#in the discord type ``?users_in_role @role_name`` example ``?users_in_role @Owner``


#for the discord token you should go to discord.dev and make an application and in the bot page create a bot and then copy its token

bot.run("BOT_TOKEN_HERE")
```

Comment: kinda copy-pasted answer, all you did is to "expand" a bit what the verified answer did

Comment: I made this code by my own two years ago