# How can I send a message if a certain user goes offline?

Tags: discord.py

My bot is made for one server, and I want to send a message to a specific channel when a certain user (bot) goes offline, how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

First, detect if there is a member update, for this you will have to enable `intents.members` like it's explained in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64148371/discord-bot-can-only-see-itself-and-no-other-users-in-guild/65241721#65241721).
To detect member updates, there is the event `on_member_update`:

```py
@bot.event #could be client.event for you
async def on_member_update(before, after):
```

then, check if the one who got updated is the one who should be looked for:

```py
user = await bot.fetch_user(user_id_of_user_to_look_for) #could be client.fetch_user for you
if user == after:
```

then check if the status was changed to offline:

```py
if before.status != discord.Status.offline and after.status == discord.Status.offline:
```

and then send a message to the channel where `channel` is the channel object of the channel you want to send the message to:

```py
await channel.send("User went offline")
```

---

### References

- [on_member_update(before, after)](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.on_member_update)
- [bot.fetch_user(user_id)](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.fetch_user)
- [Member.status](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Member.status)