# discord.py get online members

Tags: discord, discord.py

I'm trying to get all online members (with Bots) via this Code:

```
@client.command() async def printstats(ctx):
    #define the variables
    oc = 0
    for user in ctx.guild.members:
        if user.status != discord.Status.offline:
            oc+=1
```

However, all as I get a result, is the number 1, even though there are 200 members online.
I already searched through the whole internet amd couldn't find a solution that worked. Could you please help me?

Comment: Have you enabled the necessary Intents in the Developer Portal?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord Bot can only see itself and no other users in guild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64148371/discord-bot-can-only-see-itself-and-no-other-users-in-guild)

Answer (score 0):

You have this issue because your bot is not using the presence intent, hence the bot can only see itself as online, and no other users, hence the value of 1. To fix this, you need to:

- Enable the presence intent and server members in the developer portal
- Then make sure to enable this intent in your code like so:

```
intents = discord.Intents()
intents.presences, intents.members = True, True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="?", intents=intents) # whatever your prefix is etc, or client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
```