# discord.py: Looping through a list of members does not work

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```py
@bot.command()
async def start(ctx):
     CUSTOMER_IDS = []

     for member in ctx.guild.members:
          for role in member.roles: 
               if role.id == CUSTOMER_ROLE_ID: 
                    print(f'{member} has the customer role!')
                    CUSTOMER_IDS.append(str(member))

               else:
                    print(f'{member} does not have the customer role!') 

     print(f'\n{CUSTOMER_IDS}')
     await ctx.reply(f'List: `{CUSTOMER_IDS}`')
```

It's supposed to loop through the guild's members and validate whether they have a role or not. I tested this on my server with about 500 members (300+ have the role) and it only returned 1 member and 2 checks of the bot itself.

[image: unknown]

Comment: I cant answer your question, but print the role.id (or the role) in the loop and it might be obvious, and also show us how you set CUSTOMER_ROLE_ID

Comment: Did you try printing out what ctx.guild.members contains ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord Bot can only see itself and no other users in guild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64148371/discord-bot-can-only-see-itself-and-no-other-users-in-guild)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel what is most likely happening in this scenario is that discord.py rightfully doesn't keep all of that data cached. Instead what you'll need to do is make the REST API requests for what you are trying to do. So in this case, you could try the following:

```
guild = bot.get_guild(ctx.guild.id)

# It is far more efficient to get the members from the role rather
# the role from the members.
role = guild.get_role(CUSTOMER_ROLE_ID)
customers = role.members

# from here you have a list with all the member objects of people with the role
# so you can do as you wish with them from there, for example:

print(f"Customer ID's: {[m.id for m in customers]}")
```